# macOS PATH is messed up. "Command not found"

Tags: macos, terminal, path, command

For as long as I can remember I have "command not found" issues and always end up using "npx" as a workaround. I am trying to use commands for sanity.io to no avail.

This is what shows when I run "echo $PATH" command. I have tried solutions available online but I can't get it to work

```
/Users/kevin/anaconda3/bin:/Users/kevin/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/kevin/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

Comment: Please give more informations about solution you already try

Comment: what is the output of `npm get prefix`? and as @SébastienREMY said give us more info about what you have tried